# how to add version field (1.0.1) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called project and i've a column named version. I assigned a float field to the version column as:

```
t.float "version"
```

I've my view as

```
<div class="accountname">
<%= f.number_field :version, step: :any %>
</div>
```

Everything is working file but when i type the version field as '1.0.1' it is not accepting. What field I should use for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `String`. '1.0.1' is not a float.

Comment: Nor is it any other kind of number.